# Copy Microsoft Word text and equations as mathml and text together

Tags: ms-word, copy, mathml, equations

I have text with equations in Microsoft Word 2013. I want to copy this text with equations together, but what I need is, text as plain text and equations as mathml.
When I copy mathml only **Equation Options -> Copy MathML to clipboard as plain text** worked perfectly. However if I copy equation with text, all comes as plain text only.

Is there any way to copy text with MathML?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do it without some sort of pre- or post-processing.

Taking the latter first, if your document contains only text and OMML equations, when you copy it, one of the clipboard formats Word provides to the Windows clipboard is HTML. In this HTML, the equations are present, but are coded with OMML, rather than MathML. You would need a script or some other means of converting the OMML into MathML (and presumably removing all the other MS-specific markup that you probably don't want in the final document).

The other way is to pre-process it. MathType will do this with its **Convert Equations** command on the MathType tab in Word. In the Convert Equations dialog, choose to convert OMML to MathML, and after it's finished, copy the entire text+MathML document to wherever you want to paste it. (Or save it as a .txt file.)